# Storing profile pic with profile data

Tags: php, file-upload, mysqli

So I have this code at the moment but it only stores the pic in the folder and doesn't get beyond that step.
The data input in the form doesn't get stored in the db.... :(

```
<?php 
$sub=0;
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
if(isset($_REQUEST['submited'])) {

// your save code goes here

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "";
if (file_exists("media/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo "<font size='4' color='red'><b>We are sorry, the file you trying to upload already exists.</b></font>";
}

else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"media/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$sub= 1;
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "cms");

// TODO - Check that connection was successful.

$name = $_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$about = $_POST["about"];
$visible = $_POST["visible"];
$admin = $_POST["admin"];

$file_path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO schauspieler (
name, surname, about, visible, admin, date, file_path, photo_type, photo_size
) VALUES (
'$name', '$surname', '$about', $visible, $admin, '$file_path', '$type', '$size', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)");

// TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded

// "s" means the database expects a string
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name, $surname, $about, $visible, $admin, $file_path, $type, $size);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();



echo "<font size='7' color='red'><b> Success! Your photo has been uploaded.</b></font>";
}

}
}
else
{
echo "<font size='4' color='red'><b>We are sorry, the file you trying to upload is not an image or it exceeds 2MB in size.</b></font><br><font color='blue'><i>Only images under size of 2MB are allowed</i></font>.";
}
}
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing ?

Thanx guys

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a problem with your prepared statement.

The Query you want to `prepare()` has to have question-marks (?) instead of values. Those are taken into the query later when you do `$stmt->execute()`. It enables you to execute the query multiple times with different values.

After that, when executing `bind_param()`, you will need to supply the data type for EACH variable, not just for the first or in general.

Here is some untested code, hopefully it helps...

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `schauspieler` (
    `name`, `surname`, `about`, `visible`, `admin`, `date`, `file_path`, `photo_type`, `photo_size`
) VALUES (
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?
)");

$stmt->bind_param("sssiissi", $name, $surname, $about, $visible, $admin, $file_path, $type, $size);
```

Have a try and tell me if it worked.

And take a closer look at the mysqli-Reference on prepared statements ;)

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Have done as you told me and of course everything updates now very nicely. Only the columns for file_path and photo_type still remain empty. And in the size column there is always a 0. Meaning the file was not stored at all. Maybe something to do with the VA ?

Comment: Had a Problem with my columns and their arrangement. Had one I wasn't using any more. Now it all works like a charm. Thanx

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. So if I answered your questions, could you then accept my answer as 'solving your question'?